# Mailbox view like Facebook, with ORDER BY before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i'm looking for a solution for my query, for improving the performances.

I've just read several threads about that but (maybe to cause me) they aren't fitting for my case.
Anyway, here is my issue.

I've a msg table something like:

---

IDMSG | THREAD | SENDER | RECEIVER | DATE | MSG | READ

1521 | 2 | 20 | 43 | 05/24/2014 | hello guys | 0

1522 | 3 | 84 | 43 | 05/24/2014 | hi man | 0

1523 | 2 | 20 | 43 | 05/24/2014 | yes, of coure | 0

---

Now, you'll see that the user 20 has written 2 msg to me (43), so, on my msg index page, i'd like to print the latest msg of the thread, and sort it in a just way.

For instance:

- 05/24/2014 - (Preview text:) Yes of course - by Erick (thread 2)
- 05/24/2014 - (Preview text:) Hi man. - by Manuel (thread 3)
- 05/21/2014 - (Preview text:) I'm female - by Sandra.
  etc etc.

Currently, my real query is:

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM boxmsg 
    LEFT JOIN user ON sender = id WHERE receiver = '959749'
    ORDER BY idmsg DESC) 
 AS temp_tbl
 GROUP BY thread ORDER BY idmsg DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

So, it works right, but the performance is a real disaster.
Indeed, it scans whole database because the indexes in a derivate table have several problem.

How can i get the same result, having latest msg of a thread?

Thank you at all and sorry for my awful english.

Comment: Do you have an index on boxmsg.receiver and user.sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM boxmsg LEFT JOIN
           user
           ON sender = id
      WHERE receiver = '959749'
      ORDER BY idmsg DESC
     ) temp_tbl
GROUP BY thread
ORDER BY idmsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

MySQL specifically warns against this use of `*` with `group by` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)).

For what you want to do, try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM boxmsg bm LEFT JOIN
     user
     ON sender = id
WHERE receiver = '959749' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM boxmsg bm2
                  WHERE bm2.receiver = bm.receiver and
                        bm2.thread = bm.thread and
                        bm2.idmsg > bm.idmsg
                 )
ORDER BY idmsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Before running the query, create an index on `boxmsg(receiver, thread, idmsg)` and an index on `user(id)` (if one doesn't already exist).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM boxmsg b
JOIN (
    SELECT thread, MAX(idmsg) as idmsg
    FROM boxmsg x
    GROUP BY thread
) a
    ON a.thread = b.thread
   AND a.idmsg  = b.idmsg
```

An index on thread, idmsg will likely help improve performance